# How to check for integer under a loop?

Tags: python

```
fqas = None
while fqas not in ("yes", "no", "Yes", "No"):
    fqas = input(">>> [yes/no]: ")
    if fqas.lower() == "yes":
         print("\nAwesome! Current pay: $", base_pay + 50)
    elif fqas.lower() == "no":
        fqas_no = int(input("if not, how much do you think she deserve? \n>>> "))
        if 50 <= fqas_no :
            print("AMAZINGGGG! current pay: $", base_pay + fqas_no)
            continue
        elif fqas_no <= 50 :
            print("That's cool, current pay: $", base_pay + fqas_no)
            continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Numbers only please")
```

How do I add a last loop to check for integer under `fqas_no`? I have it checked for range, but I cant get it to check for integer. I get an invalid `SyntaxError`, when I try to use `ValueError`.

The code works fine except for :

```
        except ValueError:
             print("Numbers only please")
```

Comment: you have to `raise` the error. `except` is for try/except/else/finally blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) regarding exception handling. You need to include a `try` statement:

```
try:
    if 50 <= fqas_no :
        #etc
except ValueError:
    print("Numbers only please")
```

These two come together. Having just an `except` is incorrect syntax.

Sidenote, you should call `lower()` on the input itself. That way your code will be a bit cleaner:

```
while fqas not in ["yes", "no"]:
    fqas = input(">>> (yes/no): ").lower()
    if fqas == "yes":
        #etc
```

Comment: in the except block, clean up the spacing, remember PEP8.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to loop until you get valid (or invalid) input.  To detect an integer, you can try to convert your input to an `int`

```
try:
    value = int(fqas_no)
except:
    # loop around to try again
```

Even better, use the built-in method

```
if fqas_no.isdigit():
```

Answer (score 0):

> The except section without a try seems to be your problem.

```
base_pay = 1000
fqas = None
while fqas not in ("yes", "no", "Yes", "No"):
    fqas = input(">>> [yes/no]: ")

    if fqas.lower() == "yes":
        print("\nAwesome! Current pay: $", base_pay + 50)
    elif fqas.lower() == "no":
    try:
        fqas_no = int(input("if not, how much do you think she deserve? \n>>>"))
    except ValueError:
        print('Numbers only please')
        break

    if 50 <= fqas_no:
        print("AMAZINGGGG! current pay: $", base_pay + fqas_no)
        continue

    elif fqas_no <= 50:
        print("That's cool, current pay: $", base_pay + fqas_no)
        continue
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using you what you suggest but i still get a traceback error

Comment: Whats the traceback? Also, I did run this on a python3 environment and it works